# Python kivy storage module

Tags: python, linux, module, kivy

I am attempting to set up kivy on linux, specifically Mint 13. I have followed the instructions on the kivy site, specifically, I added the daily repository to apt, and then used apt-get to install python-kivy.

I wish to use the storage module, however, upon trying to `from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore`, it throws an `ImportError: No module named storage.jsonstore`.

I have checked dist-packages/kivy, and indeed, the storage directory, with the files, is there as expected. (It should be noted that this is the reason I used the daily repository; the stable version does not have the storage module for some reason.)

I have previously managed to get the storage module to work on my Windows machine simply by adding the module to my kivy directory, however, it fails here, on Linux Mint. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I resolved this by removing kivy using apt-get, then removing the stable repository from apt-get. I then added the daily repository again just to be sure (`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy-daily`, note the `-daily`), updated, and then installed kivy. This gave me the 1.8.0 version, which has the storage module as expected. There are some minor differences between the two versions, however, this was sufficient for me. It appears that the stable 1.7.2 version simply doesn't have the storage module in the setup.py and thus does not compile with it.